# XML deserialization using C# code and F# models

Tags: c#, xml, f#, deserialization

I have this unusual requirement to migrate some models from C# to F# and am honestly struggling a bit with XML deserialization. Here's what I have so far. The following pairing of XML + deserializing C# code + F# models works perfectly:

```xml
<nameServers>
    <hostNames>
        <AddressWrapper>
            <Address>www.blah1.com</Address>
        </AddressWrapper>
        <AddressWrapper>
            <Address>www.blah2.com</Address>
        </AddressWrapper>
    </hostNames>
</nameServers>
```

```ml
[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlTypeAttribute("AddressWrapper")>]
type AddressWrapper =
    { [<XmlElement("Address")>]
      Address: string }

[<CLIMutable>]
type WhoisRecordNameServersV2 =
    { [<XmlArray("hostNames")>]
      hostNames: AddressWrapper [] }
```

The following is just a throwaway draft, don't attach any significance to the code:

```cs
var xmlResponse = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(xmlResponsePath);
var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlResponse));
using var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stream) {XmlResolver = null};
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WhoisServiceExternal.WhoisRecordV2));
var record = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader) as WhoisServiceExternal.WhoisRecordV2;
```

And `record` does get created correctly with its properties populated. However, that XML is not really what I want to deserialize. What I really want is this:

```xml
<nameServers>
    <hostNames>
        <Address>ns1.google.com</Address>
        <Address>ns2.google.com</Address>
    </hostNames>
</nameServers>
```

The question I have is: how do I adjust my F# models so that second piece of XML deserializes correctly?

I feel silly for asking such trivial question, but I feel I've tried too many configurations of the model's properties, different attributes and names and nothing seems to work - the collection of `Address` fields are not deserializing correctly. I'm either seeing an empty collection of `hostNames` or blank `Address` properties.

I must be missing something obvious.

---

UPDATE:

Thank you for answering Fyodor. Below is my untrimmed XML and working models:

```ml
[<CLIMutable; XmlType("Address")>]
type Address =
    { [<XmlText>]
      Address: string }

[<CLIMutable>]
type WhoisRecordNameServersV2 =
    { rawText: string
      [<XmlArray("hostNames")>]
      hostNames: Address [] }
```

```xml
<nameServers>
    <rawText>ns1.google.com
        ns3.google.com
        ns2.google.com
        ns4.google.com
    </rawText>
    <hostNames>
        <Address>ns1.google.com</Address>
        <Address>ns2.google.com</Address>
    </hostNames>
    <ips/>
</nameServers>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that what you have here is:

1. `<nameServers>`, within which
2. `<hostNames>`, within which
3. An array of `<Address>`, within which
4. Plain text

And you'd like to map this to:

1. `WhoisRecordNameServersV2`, within which
2. `hostNames`, within which
3. An array of `AddressWrapper`, within which
4. `Address: string`

See the parallel? That looks like a lucky one-to-one mapping to me:

1. `<nameServers>` maps to `WhoisRecordNameServersV2`
2. `<hostNames>` maps to `hostNames`
3. `<Address>` maps to `AddressWrapper`
4. Plain text inside `<Address>` maps to `Address` inside `AddressWrapper`.

Now all you need to do is annotate the types and fields correctly:

1. `WhoisRecordNameServersV2` maps to `<nameServers>`, so it needs `XmlType("nameServers")`
2. `hostNames` maps to `<hostNames>` and contains an array, so it needs `XmlArray("hostNames")`
3. `AddressWrapper` maps to `<Address>`, so it needs `XmlType("Address")`
4. `Address` inside `AddressWrapper` maps to plain text inside `<Address>`, so it needs `XmlText`.

Putting it all together:

```
[<CLIMutable; XmlType("Address")>]
type AddressWrapper =
    { [<XmlText>] Address: string }

[<CLIMutable; XmlType("nameServers")>]
type WhoisRecordNameServersV2 =
    { [<XmlArray("hostNames")>] hostNames: AddressWrapper [] }
```

Comment: Ah perfect, thank you so much. The mapping wasn't my problem, but I got stuck on not knowing about `XmlText`! Using it in the address solves the problem. Working model:

`type Address = { [<XmlText>] Address: string }`